# Animation yoyo keep run when typing Edittext

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-animation

**when typing edit text yoyo animation keep run how to keep typing show animation Once ?**

```
text_send.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                              int count, int after) {
    
                 
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int before, int count) {
    
                    if(s.length() != 0) {
    
    
                        YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInUp)
                                .duration(300)
                                .repeat(0)
                                .
                                        playOn(btn_send);
    
    
    
    
                        btn_send.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_send);
```

**when typing edit text yoyo animation keep run how to keep typing show animation Once ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to show it only once when the user starts typing then use a bool to do so

```
boolean is_show = false;
text_send.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {

             
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {

                if(s.length() != 0) {


                    if(!is_show){
                        is_show = true;
                        YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInUp)
                            .duration(300)
                            .repeat(0)
                            .
                                    playOn(btn_send);
                      }




                    btn_send.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_send);
```

or you asking something else?